# How to end the HTTP response body for a Java based web server

Tags: java, http, xmlhttprequest, webserver, httpresponse

I am trying to write a Java web server from scratch (for learning) and I am bit stuck on how should I end my HTTP response body so that I can get the proper response object at client side.

I am see the 200 OK response, as well 2 other headers I am setting.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Even I am able to see the response I am writing on the client socket's o/p stream, but problem is that since I think I am missing proper ending of the HTTP response body so I am not able to get correct `xmlhttp.status` code and also not able to view the response in Chrome's inspect element, even though HTTP response code is 200 but response preview says "no response data available".

Below is my web server code and client code (XHR based) which I am using to call my web server.

**Web server code:**

```
package com.learn;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TestWebServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        startWebServer();
    }


    /**
     * test "backlog" in ServerSocket constructor
test -- If <i>bindAddr</i> is null, it will default accepting
     * connections on any/all local addresses.
     * @throws IOException
     */

    private static void startWebServer() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8001);

        while(true){
             // a "blocking" call which waits until a connection is requested
            /*Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();*/
            TestWebServer.SocketThread socketThread = new TestWebServer().new SocketThread();
            socketThread.setClientSocket(serverSocket.accept());
            Thread thread = new Thread(socketThread);
            thread.start();
        }

    }

    public class SocketThread implements Runnable{

        Socket clientSocket;

        public void setClientSocket(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        public void run(){
            System.out.println("####### New client session started.");
            try {
                listenToSocket();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("#### EXCEPTION.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void listenToSocket() throws IOException {
            /*BufferedReader clientSocketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter clientSocketWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));*/

            InputStreamReader clientSocketReader = (new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            OutputStreamWriter clientSocketWriter = (new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

            int clientSocketInput;
            boolean isFirstLineFeedEncountered = false;
            boolean isFirstCarriageReturnEncountered = false;
            boolean isSecondCarriageReturnEncountered = false;
            while(clientSocket.isConnected() && (clientSocketInput = clientSocketReader.read()) != 0){
                if(isFirstCarriageReturnEncountered){
                    //System.out.println("### After first CR");
                    if(isFirstLineFeedEncountered && isFirstCarriageReturnEncountered){
                        if(isFirstLineFeedEncountered && isFirstCarriageReturnEncountered && isSecondCarriageReturnEncountered){
                            System.out.println("### 2 sets of CRLF encountered.");
                            String responseHeaders = construct_http_header(200);
                            clientSocketWriter.append(responseHeaders);
                            clientSocketWriter.append("Bye from server, thank you for contacting me!!!");
                            clientSocketWriter.append("\r\n\r\n");
                            clientSocketWriter.flush();
                            clientSocketWriter.close();
                            clientSocketReader.close();
                            clientSocket.close();
                            break;
                        } else if(clientSocketInput == 13){
                            //System.out.println("### After first set of CRLF, found another CR");
                            isSecondCarriageReturnEncountered = true;
                        } else{
                            //System.out.println("### Oops, after first set of CRLF");
                            isFirstLineFeedEncountered = false;
                            isFirstCarriageReturnEncountered = false;
                            isSecondCarriageReturnEncountered = false;
                        }
                    } else if(clientSocketInput == 10){
                        //System.out.println("### First LF");
                        isFirstLineFeedEncountered = true;
                    } else{
                        isFirstCarriageReturnEncountered = false;
                    }
                }

                // identify "CR" or ASCII 13
                if(clientSocketInput == 13){
                    //System.out.println("### First CR");
                    isFirstCarriageReturnEncountered = true;
                }

                // identify "CTRL+C" or ASCII 3
                if(clientSocketInput == 3){
                    System.out.println("### Encountered CTRL+C");
                    clientSocketWriter.append("Bye from server, thank you for contacting me!!!");
                    clientSocketWriter.flush();
                    clientSocketWriter.close();
                    clientSocketReader.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                    break;
                }

                // identify "CTRL+D" or ASCII 4
                if(clientSocketInput == 4){
                    System.out.println("### Encountered CTRL+D");
                    clientSocketWriter.append("Bye from server, thank you for contacting me!!!");
                    clientSocketWriter.flush();
                    clientSocketWriter.close();
                    clientSocketReader.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print((char) clientSocketInput);
            }
        }

        /**
         * SOURCE: https://fragments.turtlemeat.com/javawebserver.php
         * 
         * @param return_code
         * @param file_type
         * @return
         */
        private String construct_http_header(int return_code) {
            String s = "HTTP/1.1 ";
            // you probably have seen these if you have been surfing the web a
            // while
            switch (return_code) {
            case 200:
                s = s + "200 OK";
                break;
            case 400:
                s = s + "400 Bad Request";
                break;
            case 403:
                s = s + "403 Forbidden";
                break;
            case 404:
                s = s + "404 Not Found";
                break;
            case 500:
                s = s + "500 Internal Server Error";
                break;
            case 501:
                s = s + "501 Not Implemented";
                break;
            }

            s = s + "\r\n"; // other header fields,
            s = s + "Connection: close\r\n"; // we can't handle persistent connections
            /*s = s + "Server: SimpleHTTPtutorial v0\r\n"; // server name*/
            s = s + "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";


            // //so on and so on......
            s = s + "\r\n"; // this marks the end of the httpheader
            // and the start of the body
            // ok return our newly created header!
            return s;
        }

    }

}
```

**Client code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label class="title">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" >
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="title">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" >
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton"  name="submitButton" value="Submit">
    </div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#submitButton").click(function(event) {

      //var message=obj["message"].value;
        var data = "message="; 
        var xmlhttp;
        try{
           // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         }catch (e){
           // Internet Explorer Browsers
           try{
              xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
           }catch (e) {
              try{
                 xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }catch (e){
                 // Something went wrong
                 alert("Your browser broke!");
                 return false;
              }
           }
         }       

        url = "http://localhost:8001/"

        xmlhttp.open("POST", url , true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = display_data;
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  

        xmlhttp.send(data);

        function display_data() {

            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 1 ) {
                    alert("OPENED");//check if the data was revived successfully.
            }
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 2 ) {
                    alert("Headers Received");//check if the data was revived successfully.
            }
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 3 ) {
                    alert("Loading response entity body");//check if the data was revived successfully.
            }

            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                alert("a"+xmlhttp.status);
                console.log("############");
                console.log(xmlhttp);
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    alert("Data transfer completed");//check if the data was revived successfully.
                }
            }
        }

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

***P.S.*** Please do not recommend me to use some Java web server API, this is for my learning on how to implement a web server so I am looking for insight on my issue.

---

**Update:** I think I got something, may be I need to also include the content length header so I included the same `s = s + "Content-Length: 51\r\n";` and now I am able to see content length header as well but still problem remains same that neither in XHR nor in Chrome inspect element I am able to see the server response.

Comment: Have you read [the spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) (which, yes, has been replaced, but is simpler to follow than the current spec)? Do your headers match what you're actually sending? Are you inserting the second CR-LF after the headers?

Comment: Also, as a general comment on your current code: don't mix reading and writing. Read the *entire* request, parse it into request, headers, and body, and *only then* write your response. Your code will be much easier to understand and debug.

Comment: @kdgregory: Yes, I am setting `Content-Length` with actual value of my data which I am sending and also I am setting CRLF control characters in the end (you can see the code I have pasted), from all this I did learn tht suppose I am sending 50 bytes but I set `Content-Length` response header as 40 then all HTTP clients will only show first 40 bytes, so I am positive that I am on right path and my headers are coming correctly. However all this still doesn't solve my issue, not sure if this is related to sending/preparing XHR request or XHR API?

Comment: If you think that the XHR is incorrect, then you should debug it with a known-good site. If you think that your server is incorrect, then you should debug it with a known-good client, such as `curl`, or by using your browser to make a simple GET request.

Comment: @kdgregory Server looks good to me, because I am see proper response using `curl` command and even a GET request gives me desired response. Now, about XHR, I am sure there is nothing wrong in that code, it is pretty straight forward. I think I am missing something, something because of which I am not able to see my server's returned data using `xhr` object nor in the Chrome's inspect element, when I make a GET request using web browser then I can see but not with XHR, but again, I am sure XHR code is correct. I am terribly missing a piece.